# Opening a terminal on mac gives error messages

Tags: mac, terminal, homebrew

I have recently started working with the terminal in an attempt to install homebrew. After installing homebrew, I've encountered an issue where every time I open the terminal, it gives me a long list of error messages, detailed below (here is just the first portion of it).

```
Last login: Mon Aug 15 10:25:20 on ttys003
Error: Unknown command: sllenv
-bash: Example: command not found
-bash: /REGEX/: No such file or directory
-bash: CASK...]: command not found
Error: No available formula with the name "[formula"
Error: Broken pipe
-bash: CASK...: command not found
Running brew update --auto-update'...
==› Auto-updated Homebrew!
==› Updated Homebrew from c7df26fed to 5047d4249.
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).

Warning: No available formula with the name "formula". Did you mean foreman?
Error: Broken pipe
Already up-to-date.
-bash: CASK...]: command not found
Error: No available formula with the name "[formula".
-bash: CASK...:
command not found
Error: No available formula with the name "formula". Did you mean foreman?
-bash: CASK...]: command not found
Error: No available formula with the name "[formula".
-bash: Troubleshooting:: command not found
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.5.9-108-95047d42
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 5047d4249e938d448ce8c80641beb4d42e90dbad
```

It then gives me a long synopsis about homebrew and ends my terminal.

I think that what caused this issue was when I made a typo in my installation of homebrew. After installing homebrew, it gave you two commands to enter in order to move homebrew to PATH.

```
==› Next steps:
   Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
      echo "eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" >> /Users/milo/.profile
      eval"$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
   Run brew help to get started
   Further documentation :
       https://docs.brew.sh
```

However the first time I entered the first command it miscopied "shellenv" as "sllenv". Not sure if this is relevant, but as you can see the first error that keeps popping up is "Unknown Command: sllenv"

So everytime I open terminal it gives me this long list of error messages that takes a minute and then ends terminal. Is there any way to fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps look in your .bashrc under your home directory using the finder.  Look in there for your typo where you used `sllenv` instead of `shellenv`.  I am guessing..